# How to convert a list located on a file to a list I can use in python?

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to get a 3d list of RGB values located as text in a file and convert it to a normal list that I can use in Python.

The list on the file looks like this `[[[1,0,0],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,0.5],[2,3,1.8]]]`.

What should I do to retrieve this list as as is, in order to use it in my code?

I tried to use functions such as split(), but I still cannot get the original list on the file because of the brackets.

Comment: Please define `normal list` do you mean a `[1,0,0,2,1,0,0,1,0.5,2,3,1.8]` ?

Comment: use the `ast` module --> `ast.literal_eval("[[[1,0,0],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,0.5],[2,3,1.8]]]")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` in this case ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)):

```
from ast import literal_eval

txt = '[[[1,0,0],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,0.5],[2,3,1.8]]]'

l = literal_eval(txt)

print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[[[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 0.5], [2, 3, 1.8]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON

```
import json
json.loads("[[[1,0,0],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,0.5],[2,3,1.8]]]")
```

gives you:

```
[[[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 0.5], [2, 3, 1.8]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse it as JSON.

```py
In [1]: s = "[[[1,0,0],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,0.5],[2,3,1.8]]]"                                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [2]: import json                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: json.loads(s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[3]: [[[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 0.5], [2, 3, 1.8]]]
```

If you want to read it from a file:

```py
import json

f = open("file_path", "r")
your_list = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) library:

```py
import ast

ast.literal_eval("[[[1,0,0],[2,1,0]],[[0,1,0.5],[2,3,1.8]]]")

# [[[1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0]], [[0, 1, 0.5], [2, 3, 1.8]]]
```

The benefit here being `literal_eval` will safely parse strings into python objects, and is not limited to json-specific syntax as the `json` module is